# Android: Using service, check if connection get broken

Tags: android, wcf

Iam connection to services trougth my app, I woul like to check if the connections gets broken, alert a message than.

Or is this taken carre of in android? 
If not, How should I take care of it? is there a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to built-in services of Android,  for example Connection with GPRS, WIFI or MOBILE 3G connection, then you can register a Broadcast Receiver that will tell the user when the connection is lost.

But if you are connecting to your custom-made services, for example ABC Application, then you would have to make your own service, that will periodically (example every 15mins) will check the connectivity with ABC Application. Hope this helps.